# Facing Issue Mongo DB ConnectionString

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, connection-string, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Can Any body tell me how to write a connection string for MongoDB if credentional are as follows:

Database Name - ABC,

Server Name - DEF1,DEF2

UserName - ankur

Password - ankur123

I have Created at My End below

```
mongodb://ankur:ankur123@DEF1:27017,DEF2:27017/ABC?maxpoolsize=250;authSource=$external;authMechanism=PLAIN;safe=true
```

But the following error occurs:

> Exception: MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: Unable to connect
>   in the specified timeframe of '00:00:30'.

Comment: Are you sure the ports are open on the server. Try to telnet to the port to see if you can connect to the server.

Comment: Thanks Brian for quick reply !!

Comment: Thanks Brian for your quick reply !!
I am using same port with different ConnectionString which is working fine but with this ConnectionString facing issue.Only difference in both connection string is login credential

Comment: I am facing same issue right now. Unity2D + Mongo+ C#